# How to get the titles of the pages that are in $routeParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find some way to get the titles of the pages that are in $routeParams. I ask you any suggestions on how to configure correctly.

In index.html

```
 <head>
    <title>{{title}} - domain.com</title>
</head>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('tareasApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

     .when("/:pageName", {
       templateUrl: "views/wizard.html",
       title:":PageName",
       controller: "MainCtrl"
       })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });    
  });
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

$scope.pageName = $routeParams.pageName;

});
```

I used this code but did not get success. How can I be adjusting correctly to work in my $routeParams?

```
myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
   var title = current.$$route.title;
if (title && $routeParams){
    for(var PageName in $routeParams) {
        title = title.replace(new RegExp(':' + PageName, 'g'), $routeParams[PageName]);
    }
}
$rootScope.title = title;
     });
 }]);
```

Comment: Isn't it `var title = current.$$route.title;`?

Comment: You're right. Already edited with your observation . It worked . I set up the: .when("/:pageName", { title:":PageName", })  and was rendered the route on each  page title.